# What is the advantage of using volatile meory as a main memory?

Tags: computer-science

I`m studying about the computer structure now.
I learned that the computer is consisted of CPU, Main memory, secondary memory.
Also, I learned that Main memory is volatile.
This is what I wonder.
Why does main memory have to be volatile?

I`ve searched about the reason, but I couldn`t get good answer.

Comment: Welcome but this post is in the wrong Stack I think.

Comment: [Volatile memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_memory), in contrast to non-volatile memory, is computer memory that requires power to maintain stored information.  When the power is removed the memory is wiped clean.  This helps protect sensitive information.

Comment: The reason computers use volatile memory is because it is cheaper and faster.  It doesn't *have* to be volatile, it has to be cheap and fast.